# Struggling with onUnload

Tags: javascript, onunload

I am trying to write some javascript which asks a user, when they leave the page, if they want to fill out a survey (however annoying this may be!). I thought my solution was found by an answer on this site. This is the code I currently have that does not seem to be working:

```
<script language="javascript">

function comfirmsurv() {

var ConfirmStatus = confirm("We would love to receive your feedback on your experience of this page. Would you like to complete our short survey?");

if (ConfirmStatus == true) {

window.open("#");

}
else 
{window.close();} 
} 
}
window.onUnload=confirmsurv()

</script>
<body>
Test
</body>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning the result of calling the function, not the function itself:

```
window.onunload = confirmsurv; // Note no ()
```

A few other issues:

1. Javascript is case sensitive, the property you are after is "onunload", not "onUnload".
2. The name of the function is "comfirmsurv" but you are assigning "confirmsurv"
3. `window.close()` : you can only close windows you open, not others.
4. There is an extra `}`.
5. The language attribute for script elements has been deprecated for over a decade, the type attribute is required, use `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: type="text/javascript" is deprecated either. In fact it only exists for old IE versions.

Comment: Wow. I'll get my coat. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Why might it be that the confirm box appears when my page opens, rather than closes?

Comment: @devundef—I suggested "text/javascript" because it was suggested in [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2.2) and it works everywhere. There is no valid MIME type that will do that. The valid "application/javascript" (and its many variants) will fail in many browsers.

Comment: RovG, well said. Although the specification says that if nothing  is specified then text/javascript must be used, the browser vendors (IE) do not like very much of specifications anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The unload property is incorrectly stated as `onUnload` instead of `onunload`. Also, the code have too many errors here and there.

The browser's console log provides a log that you can use to find the cause of error.

Here's the fixed script.

```
<SCRIPT>
function confirmsurv() {

  var ConfirmStatus = confirm("We would love to receive your feedback on your experience of this page. Would you like to complete our short survey?");

 if (ConfirmStatus == true) {
   window.open("#");
 } else {
   window.close();
 }

}

window.onunload=confirmsurv;
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have only just started learning through online tutorials.
This script still does nothing on my page though. The confirm box simply does not appear...